# каков порядок выполнения setImmediate, setTimeout?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

```
function timeout0() {
    console.log('timeout 0');
}

function immediate() {
    console.log('immediate');
}

setTimeout(timeout0, 0);
setImmediate(immediate);
```

Если выполнить этот код раз 10, то видно, что порядок срабатывания функций разный, иногда первым срабатывает таймаут 0, а иногда иммедиейт. 
Почему так?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args Schedules the "immediate" execution of the callback after I/O events' callbacks and before timers created using setTimeout() and setInterval() are triggered.

Comment: Что ты неправильно проверяете или нашли баг

Comment: Так отрабатывает на node -v 7.1.0.

на 6.9.1 работает нормально

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7145 вот вроде оно